# Indice 0 En Python y duda con el For

Tags: python, array, lista

Tengo una duda lógica.

Lo que quiero es mostrar la lista con su índice, pero sin incluir el índice cero.
Usando el ciclo while funciona pero con el for. No tengo claro porque.

```
'''super_list = ["", 
"Opcion 1",
"Opcion 2",
"Opcion 3",
"Opcion 4",
"Opcion 6",
"Opcion 7",
"Opcion 8"]

def recorrer(cadena,posicion):
#recorrido 1
posicion=1
while posicion<len(cadena):
    print(cadena.index(cadena[posicion]),cadena[posicion])
    posicion += 1
#recorrido dos
print("Recorrido mediante el for")
for posicion in cadena:
    print(cadena.index(cadena[posicion]),cadena[posicion])
    #print(cadena.index(posicion),posicion)
```

'''

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de recorrer una lista por sus indices con un `for` es usando `range` para establecer el límite. Como quieres partir del índice 1, no del cero, usas `range(1, len(cadena))`.

El código queda así:

```
print("Recorrido mediante el for")
for posicion in range(1, len(cadena)):
    print(posicion, cadena[posicion])
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta sería

```
super_list = ["", 
"Opcion 1",
"Opcion 2",
"Opcion 3",
"Opcion 4",
"Opcion 6",
"Opcion 7",
"Opcion 8"]

def recorrer(cadena):
#recorrido 1
    posicion = 1
    while posicion<len(cadena):
        print(cadena.index(cadena[posicion]),cadena[posicion])
        posicion += 1
    #recorrido dos
    print("Recorrido mediante el for")
    for posicion in cadena:
        #print(cadena.index(cadena[posicion]),cadena[posicion])
        if (cadena.index(posicion) != 0):
            print(cadena.index(posicion),posicion)
       
            
        
recorrer(super_list)
```

La línea de print(cadena.index(cadena[posicion]),cadena[posicion]) te estaba dando problemas  y por otro lado, para dejar de imprimir el 0, se sugiere validar como condición como coloqué en el if.